# Jquery display a certain class block onclick where the class comes from html5 data tag

Tags: jquery, css, html

With Jquery i'm trying to display a certain class block onclick where the class comes from a html5 data tag.

The var lightbox works tested it with a alert(). But Firebug console tells me that on that last line of code that lightbox.css is not a valid variable. I'm clearly missing something here.

```
$(document).on('click', '.lightbox-button', function () {

var lightbox = $(this).data('lightbox')
lightbox.css({ "display": "block"});
```

Comment: what did that alert display..??

Comment: you cannot use `lightbox.css(..)` . Use jQuery object.

Comment: The data from the html5 tag (thispart)

<div data-lightbox="thispart" class="lightbox-button work-item design motion">

Comment: What is `thispart`? Is thispart a ID of element or class of element? Important question is that How you you gonna link with element which you want show?

Comment: You should probably show your HTML too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to `$("." + lightbox).show();`

Comment: As of now its pure speculation. that you need to use class selector

Comment: who told you that `lightbox` is a class..?!

Comment: @Satpal, question does say - **where the class comes from a html5 data tag**

Comment: Thanks that worked, I knew it was simple forgot that part that it needs to be a class :)

Answer (score 0):

So, your variable "lightbox" is not a jquery element, it's the data stored in the lightbox button.

```
var lightbox = $(this).data('lightbox');

$(lightbox).css('display', 'block');
```

That should work... if the data contains the full selector of the associated lightbox.

Comment: Because you successfully saved one variable memory..!! That's all

Comment: Ok, that doesn't make sense. My bad. Can you try different phrasing. if I'm not mistaken, the btn data contains the selector of the associated lightbox. if you take that, make it a jquery object, you can then call jquery methods upon it.